# htaccess rule not working with filesmatch

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

```
<FilesMatch ".js">
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !".*Safari.*"
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Encoding} gzip
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.gz -f
RewriteRule ^resources/widget/(.*).js$ /resources/widget/$1.js.gz [L]
ForceType text/javascript
Header set Content-Encoding: gzip
</FilesMatch>
```

This doesnt work with a js file

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !".*Safari.*"
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Encoding} gzip
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.gz -f
RewriteRule ^resources/widget/(.*).js$ /resources/widget/$1.js.gz [L]
ForceType text/javascript
Header set Content-Encoding: gzip
```

This works with a js file but then it corrupts the rest of the page.

How can I just apply this rule to a js file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !".*Safari.*"
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Encoding} gzip
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.gz -f
RewriteRule ^(.*).js$ $1.js.gz [L]
ForceType text/javascript
Header set Content-Encoding: gzip
```

create a htaccess in the js directory and just use this.

Answer (score 0):

```
<FilesMatch "\.js$">
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !".*Safari.*"
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Encoding} gzip
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.gz -f
RewriteRule ^(.*).js$ $1.js.gz [L]
ForceType text/javascript
Header set Content-Encoding: gzip
</FilesMatch>0
```